# verifying a signature on an passport EF_SOD file

Tags: python, cryptography, content-management-system, pkcs#7

I have an EF_SOD file from a biometric passport, which I want to verify the signature for.

the openssl relevant command is

```
openssl cms -verify -in EF_SOD.PEM -inform pem -noverify
```

is there an equivalent using the pyca/cryptography library?
I'm asking this as I was not able to find any official documentation on this.